# Open port 8080 (APACHE) in ISA Server 2006

Tags: isaserver

Im using APACHE as my web server and using port 8080. Ive create a site called 
(e.g. http://test.domain.com:8080). I have a Firewall (ISA Server 2006).

How am I suppose to establish "http://test.domain.com:8080"in ISA Server?
Will I just add "http://test.domain.com" as its public name or with this "http://test.domain.com:8080"?

any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

Create a rule and related listner rule to listen on port 80 for the domain test.domain.com
Then on the bridging tab of the rule, redirect to port 8080.
(That's if you want users to use port 80 rather then 8080).

It's public name would be test.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Bravax!

Here's the step Ive done so far... first Ive created a web publishing rule, its public name
was (e.g. test.domain.com) then after establishing new web rule I went to its properties and
go to the bridging tab... I change the "Redirect request to http port" from 80 to 8080.

Then I created an "Access Rule", opening the "Http8080" protocol.

Did I made the correct setuo?

Comment: You don't want to create a access rule opening up http8080. As this is what you've done by creating the first rule.

This should accept queries to test.domain.com on port 80 and forward them on to the internal server on port 8080.

Test your access to see if it works correctly.